# Can LDAP entry belong to OU that not in its DN?

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

Can LDAP entry belong to OU that not in its DN?
For example, can the entry with the following DN belong to `OU=QA`?

```
CN=bob, OU=RnD ,DC=test,DC=com
```

Or it belongs only to one `OU=RnD`?

In another words can I find all OU of an entry by looking on its path in LDAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this given LDAP string

```
CN=bob,OU=RnD,DC=test,DC=com
```

user `Bob` is part of the `RnD` OU - nothing else. The LDAP path (or DN) **defines** where in the hierarchy the object resides.

`Bob` can be **member** of any number of groups that are located anywhere in the directory tree - but the `Bob` user object itself is **in the `RnD` OU** - nowhere else.

So to answer your question:

> Can LDAP entry belong to OU that not in its DN?

**No**, it **cannot** - the DN **fully defines** where object exists.